# Is there a Sync Provider (for Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0) for an FTP site?

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I'd like to synchronize a file directory with an FTP directory using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0. There is a provider for the file system. But is there one for an FTP site? Or I need to write my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623

You would do this just as you would a Network Fileshare Sync.  The trick is on the Machine(s) that you will be running the Sync application to have a network directory mapped to the FTP location that would have credentials saved.

From there, you follow the standard procedure of implementing the Sync to a network directory.